# как найти символ в string по индексу в c++

Tags: c++, строки

как я могу к примеру в
`string a = "home";`
по индексу `n` найти какой либо символ

к примеру:

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
string a = "home";

int n; cin >> n; //или какой то другой тип данных будет тут правильнее?
}
```

и далее нужно с помощью `n` найти символ в `a` и вывести его

как я могу это сделать?

Comment: https://www.tutorialkart.com/cpp/cpp-get-char-at-index-in-string/

Comment: cout << a[n]; Только следите, чтобы `n` не вышла за пределы строки

Comment: Теоретически для `n` правильнее тип `size_t`, но и `int` сойдет. Символ, как вам уже написали, `a[n]`. Можно также `a.at(n)` — этот способ с проверкой выхода за границы строки.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с исключением при выходе за границы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "home";
    size_t n = 0; 

    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << a.at(n);
}
```

Вариант с ручной проверкой границ:

```
if (n < a.size())
    std::cout << a[n];
```